# How to deal with optional tuple element when using rest parameters to forward arguments to curried function (with strictNullChecking)

Tags: typescript, tuples, spread-syntax, rest-parameters

**The goal:**
Get rid of the typescript error TS2345 where argument is not assignable to parameter

**The Problem:**
Im trying to curry an arrow function by forwarding all the arguments using a rest parameter and tuple as type. However, because I use a optional element and strictNullChecking it throws an error because it passes on an undefined type as possibility whilst it should (and will not use) the parameter at all if argument is not given.

**The Code (Its about the lower functions parse, format, convert):**

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore  */
import { parse, format } from 'date-fns'
import curry from 'lodash/curry'

type Formats = { [key: string]: string }
type Parse = [(keyof Formats), string?]
type Format = [keyof Formats, (Date | number)?]
type Convert = [keyof Formats, keyof Formats, string?]

// if you need prototype inheritance then convert functions to methods and bind
export class DateFormatter<T extends Formats> {
  formats: T

  constructor (formats: T) {
    this.formats = formats
  }

  parseToDate = (formatType: keyof T, date: string): Date => {
    return parse(date, this.formats[formatType], new Date())
  }

  formatToString = (formatType: keyof T, date: Date | number) => {
    return format(date, this.formats[formatType])
  }

  convertFormat = (from: keyof T, to: keyof T, formattedDate: string): string => {
    return format(parse(formattedDate, this.formats[from], new Date()), this.formats[to])
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  parse = (...args: Parse) => curry(this.parseToDate).apply(this, args)
  // @ts-ignore
  format = (...args: Format) => curry(this.formatToString).apply(this, args)
  // @ts-ignore
  convert = (...args: Convert) => curry(this.convertFormat).apply(this, args)
}
```

**Sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-fog-sw7qb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Any tips and help much appreciated!

Comment: Is this specifically a question about lodash?  If so, please tag it. If not, please provide a standalone [mcve] that can be dropped into an IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) or a link to the above code in some IDE with the proper dependencies already configured.  Good luck!

Comment: No this is not about lodash. Ive updated with codesandbox. thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you'll be able to convince the compiler to verify type safety here, especially with lodash's `curry()` typings which look like a whole bunch of overloads.  Ultimately it probably comes down to how you plan to use the code, but what do you think of something like this?  [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-moon-hzpev).

Comment: awesome, id only replace the lodash type with my own function type! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer by jcalz:

```
import { parse, format } from "date-fns";
import _ from "lodash";

type Formats = { [key: string]: string };
type Parse = [(keyof Formats), string?];
type Format = [keyof Formats, (Date | number)?];
type Convert = [keyof Formats, keyof Formats, string?];

// if you need prototype inheritance then convert functions to methods and bind
export class DateFormatter<T extends Formats> {
  formats: T;

  constructor(formats: T) {
    this.formats = formats;
  }

  parseToDate = (formatType: keyof T, date: string): Date => {
    return parse(date, this.formats[formatType], new Date());
  };

  formatToString = (formatType: keyof T, date: Date | number) => {
    return format(date, this.formats[formatType]);
  };

  convertFormat = (
    from: keyof T,
    to: keyof T,
    formattedDate: string
  ): string => {
    return format(
      parse(formattedDate, this.formats[from], new Date()),
      this.formats[to]
    );
  };

  parse: {
    (formatType: keyof T, date: string): Date;
    (formatType: keyof T): (date: string) => Date
  } = (...args: any) => _.curry(this.parseToDate).apply(this, args) as any;

  format: {
    (formatType: keyof T, date: Date | number): string;
    (formatType: keyof T):(date: Date | number) => string;
  } = (...args: any) => _.curry(this.formatToString).apply(this, args) as any;

  convert: {
    (from: keyof T, to: keyof T, formattedDate: string): string;
    (from: keyof T, to: keyof T): (formattedDate: string) => string;
  } = (...args: any) => _.curry(this.convertFormat).apply(this, args) as any;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `| never` instead of `?`:

```
...
type Parse = [(keyof Formats), string | never];
type Format = [keyof Formats, (Date | number) | never];
type Convert = [keyof Formats, keyof Formats, string | never];
...
```